# Making a page without the end file extension

Tags: php, html

Basically I want my pages to be `<baseurl>.com/page` rather that `<baseurl>.com/page.php` . How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Use mod_rewrite: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to look into is a [Rewrite Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine), if you're using Apache, I think what you want is [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

**EDIT:**

Example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^page(/?)$ /page.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: How do you actually use this?